# como cargar un archivo xls y actualizar los registros en la base de datos con php

Tags: php, mysql

hola comunidad estoy desarrollando un sistema de información donde cuenta con un modulo de inventario la idea es descargar el inventario en formato xlsx

Tengo el codigo que me descarga el archivo pero en formato xls pero quiero a formato xlsx

este es el codigo del reporte que tengo y la biblioteca que estoy utilizando es phpexcel

```
$filename = "equiv1.xls";

header( 'Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=utf-8' );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.xls' );


        include 'conexion.php';     

$hoy= getdate();
$fecha_hoy=$hoy[year].'-'.$hoy[mon].'-'.$hoy[mday]; 
$hora=$hoy[hours].':'.$hoy[minutes].':'.$hoy[seconds];      

?>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Reporte materiales de formacion</title>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" bgcolor="skyblue"><CENTER><strong>INVENTARIO MATERIALES DE CONSUMO SIGMA</strong></CENTER></td>
    <td bgcolor="skyblue"><CENTER><strong><?php echo $fecha_hoy;?></strong></CENTER></td>
    <td bgcolor="skyblue"><CENTER><strong><?php echo $hora;?></strong></CENTER></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><strong>Id</strong></td>
    <td align="center"><strong>Cod Elemento</strong></td>
    <td align="center"><strong>Elemento</strong></td>
    <td align="center"><strong>Consecutivo</strong></td>
    <td align="center"><strong>Calificadores</strong></td>
    <td align="center"><strong>Cantidad</strong></td>
  </tr>

<?PHP

$sql=mysql_query("select id_matge,descri_matg,cod_mat,descripcion,dispo_inve   from material inner join material_general inner join inventario  on cod_uni=id_matge and cod_mat=cod_prod order by descri_matg ;");
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){        
    $i++;
    $id_matge=$res["id_matge"];
    $descri_matg=$res["descri_matg"];
    $cod_mat=$res["cod_mat"];
    $descripcion=$res["descripcion"];
    $dispo_inve=$res["dispo_inve"];                                 
?>  
 <tr>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
    <td bgcolor="#fdf651"align="center"><?php echo $id_matge; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $descri_matg; ?></td>
    <td bgcolor="#ff9051"align="center"><?php echo $cod_mat; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $descripcion; ?></td>
    <?php
    if($dispo_inve<=5)
    {
        ?>
        <td bgcolor="#e86868" align="center"><?php echo $dispo_inve; ?></td>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
      ?>
      <td bgcolor="#5be571" align="center"><?php echo $dispo_inve; ?></td>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

 </tr> 
  <?php
}
  ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

si alguien me puede ayudar gracias

Comment: El código que estas mostrando es el del html si usas la librería **phpexcel** tendrías que cambiar tu código. Por lo que te recomiendo que veas este link que tiene un ejemplo [ir phpexcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Features).

Comment: No se entiende bien la pregunta. En el título hablas de **cargar** y en el contenido hablas de **descargar**. ¿Tienes una tabla en PHP/HTML que quieres descargar a tu equipo en formato xlsx? ¿Quieres cargar un xls en tu página? ¿Cargar o descargar? ¿xls o xlsx? ¿Podrías replantear tu pregunta, corrigiendo el título si fuera necesario? Gracias.